# How to fetch as a Map<String,List> in hql

Tags: hibernate, dictionary, hql

I am using Hibernate. I have a table like below.

```
department  | employee 
-----------------------
Dep1        |   Tom
Dep2        |   Syam
Dep2        |   Teakey
Dep2        |   Sam
-----------------------
```

My intention is to fetch department wise list like a map ( `Map<String,List<Department>>` )as below.

```
{
  Dep1: [Tom],
  Dep2: [Syam,Teakey,sam]
}
```

Is there any way to achieve it in hql in single query. I tried as below But didn't work.

```
select new map(d.department as dept, new list(d.employee as  emp) from Department d group by d.department;
```

Am I wrong with the query concept?

Comment: You found any answer ?

Comment: I also need same type of result, any solution yet ?